# ct-ng build never ends

Tags: build, crosstool-ng

I am facing an issue I can't resolve even after hours looking on the Internet.

Here is the problem : I am creating a cross tool chain using crosstool-ng. I achieve to do
    `ct-ng menuconfig`
and then I launched
    `ct-ng build`.

All the first steps execute well but the step `Installing pass-1 core gcc compiler` never ends and the clock near the logs freeze.

I tried to look at the build.log file but it does not show any error.
Its last line is :
    `echo timestamp > s-fixing list`

I am using crosstool-ng (1.22) and glibc (2.22).

If you have any idea of how I could solve my problem, I would be glad to hear it ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally manage to resolve by increasing RAM until the build success.